# Firebase -- no traceback or line number on error in Chrome

Tags: firebase

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.6/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var root_ref = new Firebase('https://jcatest.firebaseio.com')

function other_function() {
  // many lines of code here...
  var x = {}
  x.x()
  // many lines of code here...
}

function my_function(snap){
  other_function()
}
root_ref.once('value', my_function)
</script>
```

If I stick the above code in an html file and open it with Chrome all I see in the console is
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ... firebase:26"

In Firefox I see the actual error message:

"TypeError: x.x is not a function ... temp.html:8"

Why am I not seeing the proper error message in Chrome?

Is this a Chrome bug?  A Firebase bug?  Or am I doing something wrong?

It's a big problem for me because there's a lot of code in my callback and firebase is basically saying, "there's an error somewhere."  Not very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was reproducible on FirebaseJS version 2.0.6. With Firebase 2.2.2, errors and full stacktraces are reported correctly on both browsers.

Answer (score 3):

In the Firebase web client, the `Firebase.DataSnapshot` object has no method `value()`, but there is a `val()` method, which is probably what you're looking for.

See the [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/) docs for more information.

I suspect that the browser is not giving you the relevant error line because the error occurs in an anonymous function, but that's a guess.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the error is.  The question is why do I get the proper error message in Firefox but not Chrome.

Comment: Hi Rob.  Is anyone from Firebase looking into this?  It seems like a pretty critical bug in core functionality on the most popular web browser.  It's not about the anonymous function.  I see the same error even with a non-anonymous function.

Comment: This is caused by the way the Firebase client handles exceptions. When Firebase invokes a developer-defined callback, the client library will wrap that callback in a try / catch block, and in the event of an error, will asynchronously throw the error. While the error raised is not shown on the correct line, but the stacktrace will remain correct. Since the stacktrace remains intact, I don't think we'll make any changes to this code in the short-term.

Comment: There is no stack trace displayed.  I've modified the example code in my question to demonstrate this.  Please copy and paste it into an html file and see for yourself.

Comment: Also, I've been using firebase for a long time and this used to work properly.  I've just noticed it failing within the last few weeks.

Comment: @JesseAldridge Do you see different behavior with older Firebase versions? I see the same behavior using the v1.0.1 client, so this may have been a more recent Chrome change.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'm also seeing it with 1.0.1, so it's probably a Chrome change.

Comment: It may help to use the -debug version of the Firebase client. I get better stack traces from this. I think Chrome now depends on the [sourcemap](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) for minified code and doesn't do a lot of hoop-jumping here.

Comment: See my answer for a fix for this. Now FirebaseJS version 2.2.2 reports errors correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the callback in a zero ms setTimeout call you get the traceback.  Not sure why this is necessary.

`root_ref.once('value', function(){ setTimeout(my_function) })`

Comment: See my answer for a fix for this. Now FirebaseJS version 2.2.2 reports errors correctly.